# Interrupt an execution and print a part of information in terminal

Tags: linux, bash, shell, makefile, ocaml

This thread is about 2 questions...

A part of my `makefile` is as follows:

```
list:       all
            while IFS= read -r f; \
            do \
                ./analyze $$f & \
            done < list.txt
```

`list.txt` contains a list of filenames, then `make list` goes through the list and applies `./analyze` to each file.

I often use `make list > output.txt` to record everything that I print to `stdout`. In this case, nothing is shown in the terminal.

But I just realized that I can not interrupt the execution. I tried `Ctrl+C`, `Ctrl+D`, or `Ctrl+Z`, then the PC looks crash and nothing can be done.

The reason I just realized that is previously I had a timer around the call of `./analyze`. The code was

```
list:       all
            while IFS= read f; \
            do \
                ./analyze $$f & \
                PID=$$!; \
                (sleep 3; kill $$PID) & \
                wait $$PID; \
            done < list.txt
            sleep 3
```

Then if a call with a file spends more than 3 seconds, it will be stopped, and next file will be carried on. In the terminal, it shows a list of `/bin/bash: line 8: kill: (2970) - No such process` for the call less than 3 seconds, and `/bin/bash: line 9:  2973 Terminated              ./analyze $f` for those more than 3 seconds. The whole run can be interrupted by `Ctrl+C` (though several times), and the output can be written to `output.txt`.

Now I realize that the timer is no longer necessary. So my question is:

1) How could I modify `makefile` without timer or my OCaml code for `./analyze` so that it could be interrupted.

2) For `make list > output.txt`, How could I still print some simple information in the terminal while execution which allows me to see it progresses?

Comment: For the 2nd question, `make list | tee output.txt`

Comment: To avoid the "no such process" error: `sleep 3; kill -0 $$PID && kill $$PID`

Answer (score 1):

You need to get rid of that ampersand character:

```
list:       all
            while IFS= read -r f; \
            do \
                ./analyze $$f & <--- *** THIS ONE ***
            done < list.txt
```

Because it tells the shell to launch `analyze` in the background (and go on with the script). This is why you cannot interrupt `analyze` with ctrl-C, and most probably also why you can't redirect its output (the make command terminates before your `analyze` processes get a chance to write their output).